# Is there any way to make some kind of "aggregated" CancelationTokenSource in c#?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to implement CancelationTokenSource, which allow to aggregate two or more others CancelationToken inside? which allows me to write something like this:

```
void async Task DoSomeWorkAsync(CancelationToken Token)
{
    var cts = AggregatedCancelationTokenSource(Token, 
      new CancelationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Token);
    //Cancelation occurred:
    // when timeout will be expired 
    //  or 
    // when external Token.IsCancellationRequested will start to return "true"
    await DoSomeOtherWorkAsync(cts.Token);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`, from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642265(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a CancellationTokenSource that will be in the canceled state
>   when any of the source tokens are in the canceled state.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I missed this articles while googled to find answer)